# Upon changing object type from IEnumerable to IQueryable, started receiving LINQ context error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am new to Linq and Entity Framework. I have been tasked with changing the parameter on a method from IEnumerable to IQueryable. There are no compiler errors, but at runtime I get "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."

I have searched SO in particular and Google in general. The error is related to, as it says, joining different contexts. I'm not joining anything. The query in question works fine as IEnumerable.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //The query in question. Works as IEnumerable
    //Original code:
    //IEnumerable<Request> hasTickets = context.Requests.Where(x => x.RequestorID == User);
    IQueryable<Request> hasTickets = context.Requests
    .Where(x => x.RequestorID == User);

    //This is the method being used to scrub the data 
    //not included here). This method has been changed 
    //to take a parameter of IQueryable.
    hasTickets = SecurityTrimRequests(hasTickets);

    int hasTicketCount = 0;

    //Errors on this line when query is called. I just need
    //a count of the number of tickets a user has in the dB.
    hasTicketCount = hasTickets.Count();

    if (IsSupplyTeam)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else if (hasTicketCount > 0)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

I expected to get a count of the number of tickets assigned to the logged-in user to use for the logic of which view to return.

Before the method being used was changed to take IQueryable, the code ran fine. Now it has errors throughout. The above code is the most simple example I have.

Comment: Where does `User` come from?

Comment: User is from the HttpContext.

Comment: We need a [mre]. Show the actual code for `HostingEnvironment.Impersonate` and  `SecurityTrimRequests`. It would also be etremely helpful to know what you changed (what was the original code)

Comment: I edited the question to remove HostingEnvironment.Impersonate because that method is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: But you didn't show the code of `SecurityTrimRequests` as @CamiloTerevinto asked. That's where it all happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem will be in the `SecurityTrimRequests` which is not included. The `IQueryable` is building up the `Linq` commands, then executing at the time of the `.Count()`, where `IEnumerable` will materialize into a list of objects, then the code is working against the materialized list.

One way to accomplish the same thing, is to return your `IEnumerable` list with `.AsQueryable()`, which will convert your list to `IQueryable`.